# Magento2 Product you've requested does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1, delete

I've deleted product from backend.

Now I'm loading product in batch by using **productRepository** in helper.

In that process I've that deleted product Id so when ever process comes to following line

```
return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
```

I'm getting that error. So now what can be done to check if product is deleted then just return null.

```
if($this->_productRepository->getById($id))
{
   return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
else
{
   return ;
}
```

Above code also return the same error and execution get stopped.

Comment: are you want to pass null if product not found?

Comment: yeah but even checking in if it throws error.

Comment: please let me know if you have query

Answer (score 1):

You have to set inside try/catch block and check,

```
try {
    $collection = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);;
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    $collection = null;
}
return $collection;
```

Comment: How can I check if product is deleted or not because that error is coming because product was deleted...

Comment: At those place when you have faced this error. you can keep it above logic and check again same error are display? i have same error occure in past.

Comment: you can close this question after accept as answer if you helpful, so other community users have useful in future.

Comment: It will still throw an error when it reach to     $collection = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);